# Get context in nextjs

Tags: next.js

I am using Next.js and i want to get the auth0 data in `_app.js`.

```js
AppComponent.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const { req, res } = ctx;
  const tokenCache = auth0.tokenCache(req, res);
  const { datToken } = await tokenCache.getAccessToken();

  return { t: datToken }
}
```

But when i do this i get:

```css
Server Error
Error: Request is not available
```

Why i get this error, and how to get data from auth0 in `_app.js`?

Answer (score 0):

On `_app` level, the first parameter to `getInitialProps` is of type `AppContext`, which does not have `req` or `res`.

Instead, it has `ctx` which is of type `NextPageContext` and that has those.

So try to replace

`const { req, res } = ctx;`

with

`const { req, res } = ctx.ctx;`

Additionally, you could think about renaming the parameter to something like `appContext` if you wish.

Comment: it is working, but when i want to change the route i get: `Error in error page `getInitialProps`:  Error: The tokenCache method can only be used from the server side`. But i need when i change the route o keep that token every time in every page. What is the issue?

Comment: Well I think then you'll need to check that your code is only run on the server. 
You can achieve that by for example checking like this 

if(typeof document === 'undefined') { 
// means we're on the server
}

If you'd like this  to remain during navigation, store in the React state in you _app.js. and access it from there.

Comment: could you help please with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410826/get-accesstoken-in-auth0